# Django logging not working at all levels with a valid config?

Tags: django, logging

I have a valid django config in my `settings.py`, i know this as the file path is taken into account for the `RotatingFileHandler`.  My problem is that logs of logging.DEBUG are not printed to the file.

My settings and file in which the logger is run are below:

```
# settings.py
DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG
DEFAULT_LOG_PATH = 'foo/logs/foo.log'

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': 'TEST {asctime} {module} {levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'default': {
            'level': DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL,
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': DEFAULT_LOG_PATH,
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'kapsule': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
        },
    },
}

# foo.py
logger = logging.getLogger("foo.monitor")
logger.debug('debug') # nothing
logger.info('info') # printed fine
logger.warning('warning') # printed fine
logger.error('error') # printed fine
logger.critical('critical') # printed fine
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helpful little line was found in a completely separate file, which disabled logging at the debug level, once this was removed the logging worked as expected:

```
# bar.py
logging.disable(logging.DEBUG)
```

documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html#logging.disable).  I hope this can save someone else a few hours of frustration.